# Streaming Audio to a Device via MediaRouter

Tags: android, routes, audio-streaming

I want to stream an audio file from my android device to another via the MediaRouter Class. As far as I understood I need the

```
mediarouter.addCallback(MediaRouter.ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO, mCallback);
```

function to listen if a connected Device is playing audio. However I'm not sure about that. 
My Question is how do I get the audio stream ?

Answer (score 1):

If you play your audio using `AudioTrack` you need to make sure that the `streamType` matches the route's `streamType`. To get the route's `streamType`, simply do:

```
private final MediaRouter.Callback mMediaRouterCallback =
    new MediaRouter.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
                Log.i(TAG, "streamType = " + route.getPlaybackStream());
        }
};
```

Usually it will be `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC`. So when you initialize your `AudioTrack` make sure to:

```
_audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                sampleRate,
                channelConfig,
                audioFormat,
                bufferSize, 
                mode);
```